# What is the point to use the setAttribute method when there is better way

Tags: javascript

Here I have two functions `setImage1` and `setImage2` to add a value to the 
`src` attribute and the `alt` attribute for the `dieImg` object.

I find the second solution `setImage2` much easier and shorter then the first one.

So my question is if it's any point to use the first solution where you use 
the setAttribute metod
The result from these two function is the same.

A second question when do I have to use the setAttribute method ?

```
function setImage1(dieImg) {
  var dieValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);

  dieImg.setAttribute("src", "img/die" + dieValue + ".png");
  dieImg.setAttribute("alt", "die image with " + dieValue + " spot(s)");
} // end function setImage1


function setImage2(dieImg) {
  var dieValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);

  dieImg.src = "img/die" + dieValue + ".png"
  dieImg.alt = "die image with " + dieValue + " spot(s)");
} // end function setImage2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful when you want to set an attribute which can't be a property of the node (because there's already a property with that name).

For example :

```
var element = document.createElement('img');
element.setAttribute('parentNode', 'a');
```

This makes

```
<img parentnode="a">
```

while

```
var element = document.createElement('img');
element['parentNode'] = 'a';
```

just makes

```
<img>
```

(you can see it using `outerHTML`)

Today, with the `data-*` attributes, it's less relevant.

Comment: For example these give the same result var element = document.createElement('img');
            element.setAttribute('parentNode', 'a');
            var svar = element.getAttribute('parentNode');

            var element2 = document.createElement('img');
            element2.parentNode = 'a';
            var svar2 = element.getAttribute('parentNode');

Comment: @user2658578 Check the outerHTML, you'll see that the result isn't the same. And you forgot the 2 in your code in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Most often you can use  object.attribute = value  . The moment when you should use setAttribute is when you have the name of the attribute as a variable.

Comment: No : you could have simply used the bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between attributes and properties. DOM nodes have an `attributes` object, where attributes are kept. They also have properties which belong directly to the node. `attributes` are generally tied to HTML source code, while properties may change at run time.

Say you have an input element in your code:

```
 <input value="1" />
```

Then you change its value *property*:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
input.value = 2;
console.log( input.value == input.getAttribute('value') );
// false
```

It may differ by implementation, but now the `value` *property* of this input is 2, but the *attribute* is still 1. But it'll be displayed and submitted as 2. http://jsfiddle.net/EhJUt/

Some properties can not be directly manipulated, like `parentNode` in @dystroy's response, while you can do whatever you want with attributes.